# How to find all the possible arrangements for m characters in n places in javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

I have an array of say 10,000 numbers.
I need to filter out numbers with certain patterns.
I have certain mappings like,

Odd/Even

If digit is Odd -> O

If digit is Even -> E

H/M/L

If digit is between 7-9 -> H

If digit is between 4-6 -> M

If digit is between 0-3 -> L

Now let's take a number say 982.
In O/E it will convert to OEE
In H/M/L it will convert to HHL

I want to give dynamic filters for numbers with variable number of digits.

m-> no of characters to be arranged

n-> no of places in which the characters are to be arranged
Say if it is a two digit number, then number of possible arrangements

The number can be either O or E

O/E,m=2, n=2

2*2 = 4

OO, OE, EO, EE

The number can be H or M or L

H/M/L, m=2, n=3

3*3 = 9

HH, MM, LL, HM, MH, HL, LH, ML, LM

Now for a three digit number, number of possible arrangements

O/E, m=3, n=2

2*2*2 = 8

OOO, EEE, OOE, OEO, EOO, OEE, EOE, EOO

H/M/L, m=3, n=3

3*3*3 = 27

And for more number of digits and more classification factors

So how do I find all the possible arrangements for m characters at n places(*with repetetion) when m and n can be dynamic.

I looked up on the web for solution and found solution to problem similar to this but not to this exact problem.

Here's the code I found:

```
//Write a JavaScript function that generates all combinations of a string.
function substrings(str1)
{
var array1 = [];
  for (var x = 0, y=1; x < str1.length; x++,y++) 
  {
   array1[x]=str1.substring(x, y);
    }
var combi = [];
var temp= "";
var slent = Math.pow(2, array1.length);

for (var i = 0; i < slent ; i++)
{
    temp= "";
    for (var j=0;j<array1.length;j++) {
        if ((i & Math.pow(2,j))){ 
            temp += array1[j];
        }
    }
    if (temp !== "")
    {
        combi.push(temp);
    }
}
  console.log(combi.join("\n"));
}

substrings("dog");
```

This doesn't give solution to my problem.

Comment: Actually I am still at an early stage of learning and implementing programming logic. I was trying to solve this problem, but even after thinking a lot I couldn't figure out anything, I looked up to the web and found many solutions for problems similar to this but none for this exact problem. I'll update the question with the code I found online.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
findAllPossibleArrangements(charset, prefix, n, k){//n-> No of all given alphabets, k->length of desired string
        if(k==0){
            console.log(prefix);
            return;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
            var newPrefix = prefix  + charset[i];
            this.findAllPossibleArrangements(charset, newPrefix, n, k-1);
        }
    }
```